# Smart table bug

Tags: sapui5

I have created a Smart Table with useTablePersonalisation="true", annotated the oData and all works fine. The data gets displayed and I can hide/show columns using table personalisation dialog, but when using the same dialog to sort/gorup/filter I get the following error:

```
/webapp/resources/sap/ui/comp/smarttable/SmartTable.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined(…)
```

I have notcied the same behaviour in SAP examples.
Here is a Smart Table along with smart filter and the sorting works fine:
[Smart Table with Smart Filter](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtable/preview)

Whereas here is a Smart Table without the smart filter and getting the same error in the console:
[Smart Table WITHOUT Smart Filter](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.personalization.example1/preview)

Comment: Voting to close since the bug is no longer reproducible. SAPUI5 fixed the issue long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

It is look like a bug, you can change ui5 version to 1.28.3 from CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+P shorcut, it is working.